# Design Patterns examples in real (open-source) projects

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, open-source, software-design

For a project, I'm looking for actual examples of design patterns in real projects or applications; for example, I found Observer and Singleton pattern in Elasticsearch. Does anyone know a well-documented project which uses design patterns and could provide examples in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Java Spring Framework](https://spring.io/) and its related projects is a framework for developers to build applications on the Java platform.

This was one of the first frameworks to popularise the [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) design pattern and is built on top of a wide range of design patterns including the Singleton, Builder, Proxy, Template Method, Repository and many others.

You can read about some of the patterns used with some sample code in [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-framework-design-patterns).